# Reader macro debugging

Tags: debugging, lisp, reader-macro

Here's the situation:

```
CL-USER> [bookid]
#<CLSQL-SYS:SQL-IDENT-ATTRIBUTE BOOKID>
CL-USER> (sql-expression :attribute 'bookid)
#<CLSQL-SYS:SQL-IDENT-ATTRIBUTE BOOKID>
CL-USER> [books.bookid]
#<CLSQL-SYS:SQL-IDENT-ATTRIBUTE BOOKS.BOOKID>
CL-USER> (sql-expression :attribute 'books.bookid)
#<CLSQL-SYS:SQL-IDENT-ATTRIBUTE "books.bookid">
```

Clsql's [] reader macro behaves differently than sql-expression. I'd rather use sql-expression inside macros, because the reader macro can act oddly there. I tried macroexpand-1, but I'm guessing it doesn't catch the expansion early enough. How does one explore the workings of a reader macro?

Edit:
Found a solution for my clsql issue:

```
(sql-expression :table 'books :attribute 'bookid)
```

I'd still like to know about the read macro thing.

Answer (score 1):

Reader macros are handled at read-time, not macroexpansion-time, so yes: too late for what you are trying to do. But you can just quote the expression. For example, with a simple infix reader macro, since I don't have clsql installed:

```
FOO> [1 + 2]
3
FOO> '[1 + 2]
(+ 1 2)
```

I suppose this would yield the `sql-expression` invocation (or something similar) in your case.

See also: [Quote a reader macro invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188272/quote-a-reader-macro-invocation).

Answer (score 1):

To see the expansion of a reader macro, you need to `read` something:

```
? (read-from-string "[books.bookid]")
```

Since the *R* in *REPL* stands for `READ`, the normal REPL (read eval print loop) already reads the input and thus does run the reader macros. To prevent the evaluation, you need to quote it:

```
? '[books.bookid]
```